# How would I access a value using Rails Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

So, I am trying to get my head around Associations in rails (I'm using 5.1.5).

I have things working partially, but I am trying to get the `bank.title` which is for the associated bank account when I get back a list of payments.

I can't seem to for the life of me work it out, how would I go about this or is there a better way to do this?

```
user
  has_many :payments
  has_many :bank_accounts
  has_many :banks, :through => :bank_accounts

payments
  belongs_to :user

  # References: user_id and bank_account_id

bank_account
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bank

  # References: user_id and bank_id

bank
  has_many :bank_accounts

  # Has a field title I would like to access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your setup works ok, you should be able to retrieve an array of the banks relative to one user :

```
user.banks
```

or

```
payment.user.banks
```

As you'll get an array, you'd have to iterate over it to get the title (`user.banks.map(&:title)`being the shortest one)

This is what you have for now, you can't know (yet) to which bank a payment refers to, as a single user can have many banks.

If you want to get the bank associated to a payment, you need to specify a `bank_id` on the `payments` table and add `belongs_to :bank` to your `payment` model. So you'd get, from a single payment record :

```
payment.user
payment.bank
```

One may consider adding constraints to the payment model :

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :bank_id, presence: true
```

And to make things safe, validates that the bank specified for a payment is already owned by the user :

```
validate :user_owns_bank

def user_owns_bank
  user.banks.include?(bank)
end
```

**--EDIT--**

So you have a `bank_account_id` on payments.

You should add :

- `has_many :payments` on your bank_account model
- `belongs_to :bank_account` on payment model

So then you could reach it via :

```
payment.bank_account.bank.title
```

Still, this solution/setup is acceptable, but i'd advise you to refactor it from what i've described above; I would not store a reference to join table. But everyone can have its approach as long as it works.

The validation on the user ownership of the account still applies though, but should be moved to your payment model :

```
validate :user_owns_bank
def user_owns_bank
  user.bank_accounts.include?(bank_account)
end
```

<sup><sub>(this last one is un-tested; but more to insist on the fact that this very validation would make a lot of sense, you want to avoid creating a record with an account does not own — but you might have already planned this, am not seeing all your code)</sub></sup>

Comment: At present i have `payment.bank_account_id` which returns the ID of the users `bank_account`. The `bank_account` is then what references the `bank_id`, so I can grab the `bank.title`. but I my issue is I can't seem to get that I even tried adding `has_many and through`

Comment: I see, let me check

Comment: @Alan edited the answer, but as said, you might try to review your setup as described initially, if it is possible in your position on the project/have time

Comment: Yeah, i will look at refactoring it once I have things working. I kinda want to get the basics up so it can be used so I can get feedback. I still can't get it working haha associations is a pain. I get the error `column bank_accounts.regular_payment_id does not exist` which is correct.

Comment: This is what I worked out... not sure if it helps? 
**A user can have many bank accounts.**,
**A bank account can have one bank.**,
**A user can have many payments.**,
**A payment can have one bank account.**

Comment: I think you're telling us things little by little (: … if `regular_payment_id` pops-up now, I can't really help it does not show anywhere in your description, so you might have inserted it somewhere else (you should get `payment_id` instead of `regular_payment_id`, and things should work)

Comment: And know associations enough to have answered you since the beginning on the relations setup you've just described in bold yep

Comment: sorry that should have been payment_id not regular_payment_id haha

Comment: Basically `SELECT  "bank_accounts".* FROM "bank_accounts" WHERE "bank_accounts"."payment_id" = $1 LIMIT $2` the error is right as there is no payment ID as the `bank_account` is just that. the payment is associated with the `bank_account`

Comment: I think the code I posted originally is correct. The `payment` references the `bank_account`. `bank_accounts` reference the `bank`but there is no way for the payment to access the bank title which is why i thought `:through` was the right direction, maybe not?

Comment: **bank_account has_many payments**, right ? this one was missing from your relations description above

Comment: Mate, thank you so much, it worked I obviously had the associations wrong. Thanks again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a `has_one` relation to payment model for bank object which connects through bank account to get it accessed from payment model.

```
# References: user_id and bank_account_id
payments
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bank_account

  has_one :bank, through: :bank_account
```

Now you can access bank name with payment model object as

```
payment.bank.title
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, and you should be able to access payments of a particular user(say user with id = 1) by

```
@user = User.first
@user.payments
```

This will give you a list of all payments of the first user and similarly the list of  banks of a user(with id=1),

```
@user = User.first
@user.banks
```

Comment: Yeah I can get all the payments back for a user, but I have a payment associated with a users `bank_account` and that references the bank_id, which is on the bank model. :)

Comment: Then may be you should not have (users has_many :payments)instead you should associate bank accounts and payments model.So that a user can view its payment through a bank account.

Comment: Already have that as I am pulling back the payments for each current user :)